# how to place anchor points for an object on hovering in html5

Tags: html5-canvas

I have an object and now i want to show the anchor points in order to increase or decrease the width of object on hovering.

How can i achieve this from HTML5 canvas?

[image: Flow chart sample]

How to join the objects by using the canvas library?

Answer (score 1):

**A canvas drawing library would give you a shortcut to user-rescaling.**

Here is an example of the FabricJS canvas drawing library automatically displaying anchor points.  The user can resize and rotate with the anchor points.

[image]

You can download the FabricJS canvas library here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

After you download the library, you need to go to the “dist” folder and copy the “all.min.js” file to your scripts folder.  Be sure to reference “all.min.js” as a script in your html file.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/g33Vp/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/all.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:30px; }
    canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        // tell FabricJS to manage your canvas drawing
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

        // draw a Fabric rectangle on the canvas
        // the rectangele comes with drag/scale/rotate built in!
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 150,
          top: 150,
          width: 75,
          height: 50,
          fill: 'green',
          angle: 20,
          padding: 10
        });
        canvas.add(rect);

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <br/><p>Click on the green rectangle to activate anchor points</p>
    <br/><p>Then drag the anchor points to resize / rotate</p><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now how can i join with line in the above mentioned image?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle showing a connecting line between 2 shapes: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/uSa95/